# Is it possible to echo different contents to different files created in a bash range for loop?

Tags: bash, scripting, range, echo, io-redirection

I am trying to created a script called `create.ip.list.txt.sh`

when ran I would like the output to be as follows:

```
[root@ubuntu]$ head li*
==> list1.txt <==
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.101
192.168.1.102
192.168.1.103
192.168.1.104

==> list2.txt <==
192.168.1.105
192.168.1.106
192.168.1.107
192.168.1.108
192.168.1.109

==> list3.txt <==
192.168.1.110
192.168.1.111
192.168.1.112
192.168.1.113
192.168.1.114
```

This is the script I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
for i in list{1..3}.txt; do
        echo -e -n "\b192.168.1.10"{0..4}"\n" > $i
        echo -e -n "\b192.168.1.10"{5..9}"\n" > $i
        echo -e -n "\b192.168.1.1"{10..14}"\n" > $i
done;
```

But when I run the code, this is the output I get:

```
[root@ubuntu]$ head li*
==> list1.txt <==
192.168.1.110
192.168.1.111
192.168.1.112
192.168.1.113
192.168.1.114

==> list2.txt <==
192.168.1.110
192.168.1.111
192.168.1.112
192.168.1.113
192.168.1.114

==> list3.txt <==
192.168.1.110
192.168.1.111
192.168.1.112
192.168.1.113
192.168.1.114
[root@ubuntu]$
```

It loops and creates separate files as desired but it seems to be echoing the last echo command to all the files.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or may you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

I apologize if this has been asked already but I have tried to look around for the solution and nothing quite like my scenario pops up. Usually, the posts has the range loop write to a single file where here I want multiple files created from the range loop.  Maybe I am not using the proper terminology when searching, but any help would greatly be appreciated. Please do not penalize me if this question has already been asked. If it has, please let me know and I can remove the post or relocate it if needed.

Sincerely,

A humbly committed student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It will write the same thing to all the files because you're not changing what you write inside the loop based on which file you're on. It expands the curly-brace expansions independently and completely on each line; the only reason the three files are created separately is that the first such expansion is part of a `for`...`in` loop initialization clause. It might make more sense once you look at what your code looks like after curly expansion:

   ```
    for i in list1.txt list2.txt list3.txt; do
       echo -e -n "\b192.168.1.10"0"\n" "\b192.168.1.10"2"\n" "\b192.168.1.10"3"\n" "\b192.168.1.10"4"\n" > $i
       echo -e -n "\b192.168.1.10"5"\n" "\b192.168.1.10"6"\n" "\b192.168.1.10"7"\n" "\b192.168.1.10"8"\n" "\b192.168.1.10"9"\n" > $i
       echo -e -n "\b192.168.1.1"10"\n" "\b192.168.1.1"11"\n" "\b192.168.1.1"12"\n" "\b192.168.1.11"13"\n" "\b192.168.1.1"14"\n" > $i
    done
   ```
2. You only see the last thing written because you're using `>`, which overwrites the entire file. If you're going to redirect each line separately, you would want to use `>>`, which appends at the end of the file without erasing what's already there.

But it would be simpler to just use a couple nested counting loops and some math, and redirect the whole inner loop to the file as a single redirection that can still use `>`:

```
for i in {0..2}; do  # or for (( i=0; i<3; ++i )); do
  for j in {0..4}; do  # or for (( j=0; j<5; ++j )); do
    let b=100+i*5+j
    printf '\b192.168.1.%d\n' "$b"
  done >list$((i+1)).txt
done
```

I used `printf` instead of `echo -e -n`, because `printf` is both simpler and portable to more shells than just bash. I'm not sure why you are writing a backspace to the beginning of each line of your text file of IP addresses, though; if you drop that you could use just `echo 192.168.1.$b`.

In response to your comment about going past 255: if you want to perform arithmetic on IP addresses, I would consider using something other than the shell and its built-in arithmetic features. There are likely a number of special-purpose IP-manipulating tools available in your friendly neighborhood package manager, but you can use something that's probably already installed, like Ruby:

```
ip=192.168.1.250
for i in {0..2}; do
  f=list$((i+1)).txt
  for j in {0..4}; do
    printf '\b%s\n' "$ip"
    ip=$(ruby -ripaddr -lpe '$_=IPAddr.new(IPAddr.new($_).to_i+1,2)' <<<$ip)
  done >"$f"
done
```

After which `list2.txt` looks like this:

```
192.168.1.255
192.168.2.0
192.168.2.1
192.168.2.2
192.168.2.3
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Mark. The solution you provided was tested and works.  Thanks for pointing out using `printf` instead of `echo` since I like scripts to be as cross-shell platform as possible.  The reason i used the backspace was because the original script was creating a leading space when writing the new line. 

Just to confirm, the "%d" in the `printf` statement is a decimal number and the "$b" is what populates it from the `let` declaration, correct?

What if I had to expand to the ips to 255, either to 3 files or more, I would just need to figure out the math?

Comment: To be clear, `echo` is universal, but as soon as you add the `-n` and `-e` options it becomes bash-specific. 
Yes `%d` is for "decimal"; the shell has integer values and arithmetic inside `let` statements and `((`...`))`, but outside of those contexts all parameters are strings; `printf "%d"` will throw an `invalid number` error if the corresponding argument string doesn't parse as a number.
If you wanted to go past `.255` in the last octet of the IP address, then yeah, you'd need to break out some more math; I would vote for more sophisticated tools than the shell in that case.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any loop if you use `printf`.

Moreover if you want to split content based on some number of lines, use `split` command.

```
printf "192.168.10.1%02d\n" {0..14} | 
  split --lines=5 --suffix-length=1 --additional-suffix=.txt \
        --numeric-suffixes=1 - list
```

Comment: That assumes GNU split, FWIW. Doesn't work on the `split` that comes with Macs, which doesn't have the `--additional-suffix` feature (or support long options for the other values).